# Bazel build command line pass copt argument to just a specific cc_library/cc_binary?

Tags: c++, command-line, build, bazel

I want to use a **variable** `copt` argument to build **a specific target**. so I use the `--copt` of **`bazel build` command line**.

However bazel will **rebuild all dependencies** of the target when the `copt` changed. these is not needed.

Is there some better way to deal with the situation?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`--per_file_copt`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--per_file_copt), you can finely control the compiler options for particular files from the command line.